# Qlik View: Retrive Last Reload of another report

Tags: qlikview

In a qlik report(Main Report) i have a text object with an action that open another report. Is there the possibility to show in the text object located in the Main Report the last Reloadtime date of the report that i open with the action ?

thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while reloading the other report,

use:

`T1:
Load reloadtime() as reloadTime autogenerate(1);
store T1 into T1.qvd;`

in the Main report file:
`Load * from T1.qvd (qvd);`

you can also use `*add* Load * from T1.qvd (qvd);` if you want to use partial reload.

thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

i can use filetime() function but the last change is not necessarily the date of the last reloadtime().

I could store these information externally in a txt-file which you read in your target-application as include-variable. This will require a reload from the target. As alternatively could these value be stored in a database and read then per direct discovery without a reload.

A further option could be to transfer these information per selections by opening: AJAX and URL parameters maybe by selection a loosen dummy-date-table and these selection will then be queried per getfieldselections().